# how to set value to Foreign key filed before Perform create in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two serializers like this :

```
class MeetingLocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MeetingLocation
        fields = '__all__'

class MeetingtSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    location = MeetingLocationSerializer()
    photos = MeetingPhotoSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = ['id','title','description','date_time','time_zone','host','is_private','is_virtual','url','photos','location']
```

and this is my modelviewsets

```
class MeetingListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       
    queryset = Meeting.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeetingtSerializer
    
    
    
class MeetingPhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
       
    queryset = MeetingPhoto.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeetingPhotoSerializer
        
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        param = kwargs
        photos = MeetingPhoto.objects.filter(meeting=param['pk'])
        serializer = MeetingPhotoSerializer(photos, many =True)
    
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

when i want to post data to MeetingListViewSet and save it , the meeting filed in nested location serializer needs value which is the meeting that i am trying to create and it is not created yet! what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

So you can just set the required False and if you want to create a nested list of meeting location you can just simply create a create function  and define like i did.

```
 class MeetingtSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    location = MeetingLocationSerializer(many=True,required=False,source="meetinglocation_set")
    photos = MeetingPhotoSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        fields = ['id','title','description','date_time','time_zone','host','is_private','is_virtual','url','photos','location']

 def create(self, validated_data):

        if 'meetinglocation_set' in validated_data:
            cds = validated_data.pop('meetinglocation_set')
        else:
            cds = []

        instance = super().create(validated_data)
       
        for cd in cds:
            instance.meetinglocation_set.create(**cd)

        return instance
```